# footer always on bottom CSS on mobile and desktop

Tags: css

I was looking around how to add a footer to the bottom of the page in both mobile and desktop, I did attempt

```
    .footer
{
    height: 40px; 
    width:100%; 
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    opacity: 1;
    border-top:1px solid #9a9696;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

However this doesn't seem to work, there seems to be a gap between the bottom of the page and the footer

Comment: F12 should show you where the padding or margin is coming from.

Comment: doesn't seem to be any

Comment: I don't understand the issue! Do you have other elements in the website and the footer is under them, but when you open the page on a browser it seems on top of them for no good reason?

Comment: Pretty much

No idea if I'm allowed to post this but this is the test version 

https://gotsocial.co.uk/fresh/

Comment: `position: absolute` will set it to the bottom for desktop resolutions, for mobile resolutions you can reset it back to `position: relative`

Comment: @cakeman I took a look at you website, and answered your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code to your CSS. Should make it work normally.

CSS:

```
.footer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid #9a9696;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 1100px){ /* You can edit the max-width value to match what you need */
  .footer {
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 1;
    border-top: 1px solid #9a9696;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-top:30px; /* You can edit the value of the margin top as you need */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

remove relative and add fixed.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
}

    .footer {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 1rem;
      background-color: #efefef;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

Comment: This will fix it to the bottom even when the user scrolls, not sure that is requirement.

Comment: It's stuck on the middle of the page in mobile

Comment: how are you setting it? is it the last thing in your body tag?